# ¿Cómo definir un campo BIGINT para admitir valores superiores a 255 en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos pero al momento de querer almacenar un valor mayor a `255` no pude lograrlo.

La idea detrás por dar un ejemplo si yo dispongo de `99999`, ¿cómo almacenarlas en la base de datos?

Definición de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE cantidad (
           IDcantidad INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           total_manzanas BIGINT(255), -- Ejemplo1  no pude 
           total_manzanas BIGINT(2^16) -- Ejemplo2  no pude
           total_manzanas BIGINT(99999) -- Ejemplo3 no pude
           PRIMARY KEY (IDcantidad) 
);
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> EJ ERROR 1439 (42000): Display width out of range for 'cantidad' (max = 255)
>
> EJ ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2^16

Comment: BIGINT sí debería permitirte este valor, pues permite hasta 2^63 -1. Véase la referencia [11.1.2 Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me aparece el error ERROR 1439 (42000): Display width out of range for 'cantidad' (max = 255)

Comment: Deberías añadir, [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/408391/edit), **el intento exacto que has hecho**, **y el error obtenido**. ¿ Has revisado lo que es un [mcve] ? Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por aclararme esos puntos tomaré nota y eh editado la pregunta, Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo el tamaño del tipo de dato (ese número que indicas como parámetro de un tipo en la definición del campo de la tabla) con el valor máximo o mínimo que se puede almacenar dentro del campo (el valor que realmente introduces en ese campo de un registro de la tabla).

En particular, el error que estás sufriendo es un error [`ER_TOO_BIG_DISPLAYWIDTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_too_big_displaywidth) que indica que has proporcionado un parámetro a un tipo demasiado elevado.

Precisamente el tipo `BIGINT` ignora el parámetro proporcionado, por lo que pongas el número que pongas los datos almacenados en su interior podrán ser del **-2<sup>63</sup>** al **2<sup>63</sup> - 1** [(ver documentación)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

Para el resto de tipos que sí usan el parámetro (como `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, etc), el valor máximo que se puede configurar es `255`. Si proporcionas un valor superior, sea cual sea el tipo, se genera ese error.

**Entonces, ¿cómo poder almacenar números mayores de `256` en un `BIGINT`?**

El tipo `BIGINT` (como apunté anteriormente) soporta números superiores a `255`.

Incluso con un simple `INT` también podrías almacenar valores superiores a `255` (pero inferiores a dos mil millones y pico, 2 147 483 647 para ser exactos).

**¿Y el error de sintaxis?**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2^16

Este mensaje te indica que MySQL no sabe qué hacer con el valor `2^16` que has usado como parámetro del tipo `BIGINT`. Esto es debido a que las potencias no se calculan de esa manera en MySQL.

En un caso de querer calcular **2<sup>16</sup>** en una sentencia SQL, no se puede usar la expresión `2^16`, habría que hacer uso de la función [`POW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_pow) de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT POW(2, 16)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo eh aprendido nuevos conceptos

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví. La respuesta esta en no asignar el valor total que tengo si no dejarlo como INT

```
//Creación de tabla
CREATE TABLE cantidad (
                       IDcantidad INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                       cantidad BIGINT NOT NULL, //xD
                       PRIMARY KEY(IDcantidad)
                      );
```

//Imprimo resultado

```
SELECT * FROM cantidad ;
```

3 |   PedroNavajas | 1000
4 |   PedroNavajas | 99999

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta con la explicación del motivo tanto del problema, como de que te funcione sin poner nada entre paréntesis.